# Can I use as act-as-list with a polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-list

I am working on a [liquid democracy app](https://github.com/TheFuturistParty/debate). My data model is:

Both Users and Organizations are Voters. A Voter has an ordered list of Delegations. A Delegation consists of a set of Tags and an ordered list of Voters (delegates).

When determining which Voter to serve as proxy, the first Delegation with a matching Tag is used and then the first delegate in the list who has voted on the Issue.

To create the ordered list of delegations, I can simply add a `position` field to the `Delegation` model. [`acts_as_list`](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) can then be used to manage the order.

What I'm uncertain about is how to structure the list of delegates. It seems like the database columns should be:

- `delegation_id`
- `delegate_type`
- `delegate_id`
- `position`

My current stab is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :organizations
  has_many :delegations, as: :voter
  acts_as_tagger
  acts_as_voter
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :delegations, as: :voter
  acts_as_tagger
  acts_as_voter
end

class Delegation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :voter, polymorphic: true
  has_many :tags
  has_and_belongs_to_many :delegation_entries, -> { order("position ASC") }
  acts_as_list scope: :voter
end

class DelegationEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :delegation
  acts_as_list scope: :delegation
end
```

When I do `Organization.first.delegations << Delegation.create` from the console I see:

```
(0.4ms)  BEGIN
Delegation Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "delegations".* FROM "delegations"  WHERE ("delegations"."voter_id" IS NULL AND position > 1)  ORDER BY delegations.position ASC LIMIT 1
SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "delegations" SET position = (position + 1) WHERE ("delegations"."voter_id" = 1 AND position >= 1)
```

So, `acts_as_list` doesn't handle polymorphic associations apparently. The increment is only on the `id`, so it would update both the User and Organization. Since order is preserved, does this matter? It would likely become an issue when doing reorderings and insertions.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, this structure was replaced with single table inheritance which has a single set of identifiers, so `acts_as_list` will work.